# change background image in CSS when clicked

Tags: html, css, image

**Please can somebody tell me how to do the following**

```
.logo {
display: block;
text-indent: -9999px;
text-transform: capitalize;
background: url(../images/menu.png) no-repeat;
height: 120px;
}
```

change image so when its clicked

```
background: url(../images/menu_open.png) no-repeat;
```

**the HTML for this is**

```
<div class="sidebar">
<a href="#" onclick="return showOrHide('menulink');"><div class="logo">TEST IMAGE</div></a>
<ul id="menulink">
```

Currently when clicking the icon, the menu opens and closes,

view the full codes at
http://carbonyzed.co.uk/menu/2/index.html 
http://carbonyzed.co.uk/menu/2/css/style.css

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the background image to change permanently (until refresh or reload), or just for as long as the mouse is clicking it?

What's a test image in this context? In what way is it different from a regular one?

Comment: idealy, to toggle with menu, please see http://carbonyzed.co.uk/menu/2/

Comment: Then I suggest that you follow @Lokase's advice, or use jQuery's `show` feature.

Comment: please see comment on @Lokase's answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the best user experience, consider using a sprite, and changing the class on click, rather than changing the style attribute. So imagine you have the two images in one sprite, called menu_sprite.png

The image is 240px high, and the width of the logo. The default image is in top left, the "open" image is right underneath.

CSS

```
.logo{
  background-image: url(../images/menu_sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.logo.open{
  background-position: 0 -120px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.logo').click(function(){ $(this).toggleClass('open'); });
```

This method lets you avoid having a split-second with no image, without using preloaders.

Comment: Glad you got it working. For an example where things aren't resizing it's very handy.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".logo").click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(../images/menu_open.png)');
});
```

Comment: Really? Where has he mentioned jQuery solution? and the jquery you have written is wrong - http://jsfiddle.net/LdErY/

Comment: You can't operate the click handler with pure html / css

Comment: Jquery solution would work, however I currently have an OnClick in there for toggling the menu, can you apply multiple OnClick results? and also, can I apply an OnClick in this case, where the image is located in the CSS? Thanks

Comment: Dipak, the dude is already using jquery, so there's no need to jump all over Lokase, and you look silly now.

Comment: @puppybeard you should be careful with the comments you are posting, it can be flagged... and the solution Lokase has posted is wrong it doesn't work. it has to be $(this).css('background-image', 'url(../images/menu_open.png)');

Comment: Sorry folks, still early in the morning, corrected url syntax

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<a href="#" onclick="return ShowOrHide('menulink'); document.getElementById('id').style.background = 'url(img.img) no-repeat';" />;
```

Comment: I currently have '<a href="#" onclick="return showOrHide('menulink');"><div class="logo">TEST IMAGE</div></a>' so can i make it '<a href="#" onclick="return showOrHide('menulink');""document.getElementById('id').style.background = 'url(img.img)' no-repeat" />;'  ???

Comment: so - <a href="#" onclick="return showOrHide('menulink');";"document.getElementById('id').style.background = 'url(img.img)' no-repeat" />;

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="return ShowOrHide('menulink'); document.getElementById('id').style.background = 'url(img.img) no-repeat';" />;

Comment: in fact - <a href="#" onclick="return showOrHide('menulink')";"document.getElementById('id').style.background = 'url(img.img)' no-repeat" />

Comment: No.. dont close the quotes and open them again... 
"return showOrHide('menulink')";"document.getElementById('id').style.background = 'url(img.img)' no-repeat" should be "return showOrHide('menulink'); document.getElementById('id').style.background = 'url(img.img)' no-repeat"